# Displaying .html file directly in GWT Panel

Tags: html, gwt

Is there a way to create a GWT panel, let it display the content of my .HTML file by passing it the file's dir on server?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Normally this kind of thing is done with an IFRAME. Gwt supports this via it's [`Frame`](http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/javadoc/latest/com/google/gwt/user/client/ui/Frame.html) widget.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. You really help me out. In GWT we can set URL to a Frame by Frame frame = new Frame(URL);